# Sharing rich content with Android share sheet

Tags: android, share

I am looking at sharing functionality in our app. We basically show buttons for common social apps and also the possibility of opening the default Android share sheet. Many apps that we want to share to use special intent parameters. E.g. instagram has the option of [defining a background image plus a sticker on top of it](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/). Other apps use different intent parameters that are incompatible with each other.

I would love to only use the default Android share sheet and still share app specific rich content. According to the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#using-android-system-sharesheet), the share sheet can only take in simple data. Some rich data is possible, but only for the preview in the share sheet.

Ideally, what I would like to do is something like

- Show default android share sheet
- Get a callback when an app gets selected to share to
- Depending on what app got selected, add app specific rich content data to the intent

The only callback that I found for that share sheet is [using a BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#share-interaction-data), but it does not look like any data can be added to the original intent from there.

Anyone know if this is at all possible with the share sheet or if there is a different built in way to do this?

Bonus issue: The share sheet uses a mime type (text or image) to select which apps to show. With what I would like to do, the mime type could change depending on the selected app. E.g. share only text to an SMS app, but an image to FB or instagram.